# Loading dependencies at runtime with bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have an application with many optional components, all with their own complex dependencies. For example, some deployments might want to use LDAP functionality and will need to load ldap-related gems. But many will not, and those that don't should not have to install ldap-related gems.

How can I use Bundler to load these dependencies depending on which components users (deployers) have enabled?

I don't want to to force deployers to manually edit their Gemfiles. It has to be possible to enabled/disable components via the application's UI.

Just including every possible dependency in the Gemfile is not ideal. Some of the rarely used components require a lot of complicated native compilation. Another solution might be to have the application edit its own Gemfile. But this is kind of awkward and would likely require a restart every time components are changed.

Is there a way in Bundler to dynamically load gems in runtime? If not, are there alternatives that provide something like Bundler's sandboxing but allow for dynamic loading?

Comment: [This Bundler feature request](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1636) may be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for that link Andrew. I think we'll be in better shape if that feature request gets fulfilled (just --with would be better), but I wish it were possible to just do something like a 'Bundle.gem "gemname"' call inside of my app's code. I have a feeling that might not be possible in Bundler's current architecture, but I'm wondering if there are other similar projects out there that could do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide multiple Gemfiles and use bundle install --gemfile to use the specific gemfile and only install the Gems you need for that deployment.

In your application you could then use Bundle.setup with the appropriate groups of the previously installed Gemfile to just load the appropriate Gems

Sure thats not a nice and easy way, but should give you the functionality you want.

See
[Bundler Setup](http://bundler.io/bundler_setup.html)
[bundle install](http://bundler.io/bundle_install.html)